# PHP Imagick getImageProfiles and profileImage Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: php

```
$imageHandler = new Imagick();
    $imageHandler->newImage(800, 800, new ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));

    //获取原图的icc
    $picHandler = new Imagick("./O1CN01LYGEv01ruWjR8JpKy_!!20687556911.jpg");
    $picHandlerProfiles = $picHandler->getImageProfiles("icc", true);
    var_dump($picHandlerProfiles);
    if (!empty($picHandlerProfiles['icc'])) {
        $s = $imageHandler->profileImage('icc', $picHandlerProfiles['icc']);
        var_dump($s);
    }

    exit;
```

```
array(1) {
  ["icc"]=>
  string(940) "?KCMSmntrRGB XYZ ?
                                 :acspMSFTKODAROMM???+KODA
ProPhoto RGBXYZ ???,curv?XYZ ?4I?XYZ "??>XYZ?-descKODAK??KODAKKODAKdesc'Reference Output Medium Metric(ROMM)  (??Reference Output Medium Metric(ROMM)  'Reference Output Medium Metric(ROMM)  mmod???;?"
}
bool(true)
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```